# Issue running cURL PHP on host

Tags: php, curl

I have some problem running php scripts on my go daddy linux server host.

As you can see this code task is to get the content from cnn.com and insert everything to a new file called "example_homepage.txt". The problem is that file is created on the server, but it is blank.

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://cnn.com/");
    $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Google doesn't allow parsing theirs page. So it is **illegal**

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you regular expression does not match anything.

If you try download your URL (http://www.google.com/search?q=cnn&tbm=isch) with wget or something that isn't a browser, you can see, that you get a HTTP error 403.
It seems like Google Image Search uses JavaScript to show the results.

Also you should always check if you expression matches, before using the matches:

```
if (preg_match_all(...)) { /* match */ } else { /* no match */ }
```

Comment: Oh and what zerkms said, seems to be the reason for the "forbidden" error. :)